# run iperf in background and redirect output to a file

Tags: linux, bash, iperf, iperf3

I am trying to start iperf server in background and redirect the output to a file. But it is not working.

server:

```
iperf3 -s -D >> /tmp/listen.txt
            or
iperf3 -s -D > listen.txt
```

client:

```
iperf3 -c <server-ip> -B <client-ip> > send.txt
```

I am able to see output in send.txt on client but on server, I don't see anything being written in any file. Can someone help me with this command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the daemon option, use `nohup`:

```
nohup iperf3 -s >> /tmp/listen.txt 2>&1 &
```

That will put iperf3 in the background and make it immune to hangups. The shell will print out the job number and PID:

```
$ [1] 1234
```

You can stop it later by sending a SIGTERM using `kill`:

```
$ kill -SIGTERM 1234
```

Comment: It appears that there is [a defect in iperf3](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/438).

Comment: Oh, is there any work-around suggestion in this scenario?

Comment: Newer versions of iperf3 apparently have a `--logfile` option.

Comment: Will accept the answer considering the issue of iperf3.

Answer (score 2):

On any recent iperf3:

```
iperf3 --server --daemon --logfile iperf3.txt --pidfile iperf3.pid
```

(substitute short command line flags if you like)

The server output will go to the file `iperf3.txt`.  The process ID will be stored in the file `iperf3.pid`...you can look that up when you want to kill the process.

If you want to be sure that output makes it to the file in a more timely manner (possibly at a very small hit to performance), add the `--forceflush` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I just run it in a screen session and use '--logfile' option to capture the output.

```
screen -S iperf-server
iperf3 -s -B 10.11.12.13 -p 5001 --logfile s1.txt
```

You can do the same for client.